# Looping on elements of a class python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, instagram

I've a code for sending request to people on instagram. It scrollings following box and send requests. But sometimes it cannot find element and it gives error. I want to turn my code more general.

I takes 12 element each scrolling. How can i say that find the request button on each element?

```
  elements = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_aano"]//a/span/div')[-12:]
        for element in elements:
            button = element.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="_ab8w  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9h _ab9k _ab9p  _abb0 _abcm"])
```

but it doesn't work because it cannot find button.
[image: background of instagram]

To illustrates, _aano class which includes follower and the second class that i want to click.
Can you please help me?

Comment: I can find _`'//div[@class="_aano"]//div'`_ but I don't find `'//div[@class="_aano"]//a/span/div'` Am I missing something?

Comment: Additionally, why are you targeting the `<div>` instead of the `<button>` which you want to click?

Comment: First of all thank you for answering,  i really don't understand the difference between two codes. Can you explain a bit? I want to click the last highlighted class. There is a button class in the second highlighted class but you can click on the div also.

Comment: _but you can click on the div also_: No, `<div>`s are generally non-interactable but the `<button>`

Comment: Actually i fixed the problem thank you but i've another problem now. When i try to get follower from a user who has lots of follower, I'm having trouble. It takes too much time to scroll and it fails. How can i fix that

Comment: try be deleting users from HTML instead of scrolling